# Gauge covariant derivative with additional "inner" invariances?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance

The Lagrangian density of a Dirac field is:

$$
\mathcal{L}=\phi^*(i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -\gamma_0 mc^2)\phi \tag{1}
$$

Here, I am interested in an slightly modified Lagrangian density such that it has an extra symmetry "one level down", for example:

$$
\mathcal{L}=(\psi^T \eta \psi)^* (i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -\gamma_0 mc^2)(\psi^T \eta \psi) \tag{2}
$$

where $\psi^T \eta \psi \in \mathbb{C}$. I note that posing $\phi:=\psi^T\eta \psi$ recovers (1) above.

(2) has an "inner" Lorentz invariance (because $\psi^T \eta \psi$ is invariant with respect to $SO(3,1)$),  in addition to the usual U(1) invariance. The specific type of invariance ($SO(3,1)$) is not really the focus point, as I am interested in the general methodology for a Dirac field with a second layer of invariance at the wavefunction level. I could have picked another group for the "inner" invariance, for instance $\psi^T\psi$.

In general, how can I create a gauge covariant derivative, along with the correct kinetic term for such a Lagrangian.

My original instinct was to distribute the partial derivative as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
&(\psi^T \psi)^* (i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -\gamma_0 mc^2)(\psi^T \psi) \\
&=(\psi^T \psi)^* i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu (\psi^T \psi) - (\psi^T \psi)^* \gamma_0 mc^2 \psi^T \psi\\
&=(\psi^T \psi)^* i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu (\partial_\mu \psi^T) \psi + (\psi^T \psi)^* i \hbar \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \psi^T \partial_\mu  \psi  - (\psi^T \psi)^* \gamma_0 mc^2 \psi^T \psi
\end{align}
$$

But now I have two derivatives to work with, and I am not familiar how to proceed further.

Comment: The tensor product of spinorial irreps is not spinorial, so what is the meaning of $\gamma^\mu (\psi^T \psi)$?